# Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --out

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, phaser-framework

When building typescript in VSCode, I get the following error:

> error TS6082: Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside
>   --out.

My settings are as follows:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "out": "current/game.js",
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": false
    }
}
```

**.vscode/tasks.json:**

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
    "args": [],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Despite the error, the game.js file does get created and runs properly.

Anyone have any thoughts about what might cause this error?

Comment: I just ran into this error and performed a Google search to find the solution and I was happy to see that someone else had asked about this. Lo and behold, it was me who asked it! Thank you self!

Comment: the circle is complete when you search Google and find your own StackOverflow answers 

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It means what it says. You can’t use `--out`/`--outFile` to bundle modules together for Node.js/CommonJS, since there is no bundle format for CommonJS. Simply don’t use that option for CommonJS and corresponding JS files will be emitted for each input TS module file.

Comment: Simply removing "module": "commonjs", made this work. Thanks!

Comment: Likewise, you can also change to "module":"none".

Comment: VS 2017 complains about the choice of "none"

Comment: instead of removing commonjs, you should use the other instead, such as amd if you want to be bundled.

Comment: This is a great solution. Thank you once again!

Comment: But there is a bundle format for CommonJS. Webpack bundles CommonJS modules.

Comment: @AjaxLeung CommonJS modules are a standardised format. The standard does not include a bundle format. Webpack is a tool like Browserify, Rollup, Brunch, or r.js. It doesn’t generate “CommonJS module bundles”, since there is no such thing, and trying to load a Webpack-generated JS file into a compliant CommonJS module loader would not work.

Comment: I get `error TS6131: Cannot compile modules using option 'outFile' unless the '--module' flag is 'amd' or 'system'.`

Answer (score 2):

The [`outFile` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#outFile) in the [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) file is only available if you set
the [`module` option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) to [`system`](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) or [`amd`](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD).

As described in ["Code Generation for Modules"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#code-generation-for-modules), only
modules created for [`system`](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) or [`amd`](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) can
be simply concatenated together while keeping the same functionality.

That means, if you are using a different module system, then you could migrate all you files into AMD modules (or SystemJs), otherwise bundling is not possible with `tsc`, and you would have to use a different solution for bundling.

#### What is "bundling" with `tsc`

`tsc` can "bundle" files together, but only by simply concatenating them.
I assume they provide that functionality only because it's very easy to do.

But in order to bundle e.g. **CommonJs** files, the files would have to be **transpiled** into something completely
different, e.g. wrap each file into an individual scope, removing the `module.exports` and create
the appropriate relations between the scopes, ... That is hard work to do, and there are other libraries
that are specialized into doing it.

#### Why AMD modules do work

E.g. **AMD** works by defining modules by calling the function `define( myModule )`. These function calls can simply be concatenated, like:

module 1:

```
define( { x: 1, y: 2 } );
```

module 2:

```
define( function(){ return { hello: 'world' }; } );
```

Can be just concatenated to:

```
define( { x: 1, y: 2} );
define( function(){ return { hello: 'world' }; } );
```

and would still run in the same way. Similar with **SystemJs**.

#### Why CommonJs modules don't work

**CommonJs** modules on the other hand look like this:

module 1:

```
module.exports = { x: 1, y: 2 };
```

module 2:

```
module.exports = ( function(){ return { hello: 'world' }; } )();
```

When simply concatenated, the bundle would look like this:

```
module.exports = { x: 1, y: 2 };
module.exports = ( function(){ return { hello: 'world' }; } )();
```

That obviously doesn't work, because `module.exports` would be overwritten repeatedly.

Other module systems would cause similar or worse difficulties.

#### How to bundle OR use modules

##### You can bundle, but not use modules:

You can make `tsc` bundle your files, but if they use CommonJs modules, then the javascript just wouldn't work.

Therefore `tsc` prints a warning if you state `module: commonjs`. If your files don't contain conflicting code, then your code will run fine anyway, but then you don't need the `module: commonjs` setting.

E.g. these settings in your `tsconfig.json` would output the concatenated (but not working with CommonJs modules) `bundle.js` file:

```
"moduleResolution": "nodenext",
"outFile": "./dist/bundle.js",
// "module": "CommonJS", <-- DON'T set the `module` property
```

##### You can use modules, but not bundle:

You can make `tsc` keep the functionality of the CommonJs modules, but then e.g. the `module.exports`
assignments need to be kept separate:

`tsconfig.json`:

```
"moduleResolution": "nodenext",
// "outFile": "./dist/bundle.js", //  <-- DON'T set the `outFile` property
"module": "CommonJS",
```