# TypeScript exports is not defined

Tags: typescript, model-view-controller

I'm trying to use export and import but it not working I get an error

Here is my code HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <script src="~/scripts/user.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

User.ts :

```
export class User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

main.ts

```
import { User } from "./user";
```

Here is also screenshot of exception :

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

**Option 1:** Use a module loader like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/), Browserify, etc.

**Option 2:** If you just want to compile `*.ts` to `*.js` without any module imports or exports, set `compilerOptions.module` to "none" in your `tsconfig.json`. Note that you won't be able to export/import modules when you set `compilerOptions.module` to "none".

Comment: Can I use Webpack in ASP.NET ?

Comment: You can. Much easier with ASP.NET Core now. There are plenty of examples online.

Comment: or simply use references, than it works without any module loader and as commonjs, and you don't want to load hundreds of js files in your html i think, so only output 1 js file

Comment: I set compilerOptions.module to ESNext and it solved the issue, allowing me to use "export" like asked in the question.

Answer (score 19):

try the following changes

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <!-- <script src="~/scripts/user.js"></script> --> <!-- not longer needed -->
    <script src="~/scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outFile": "~/scripts/main.js",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es5",
      "es6"
    ]
  }
}
```

with this config your output is only one js file what can be uglified wunderfull, containing all referenced files in the main.ts. i just don't know if ~/ works or if you have to set the path relative to the config file, i'm not working with linux.

User.ts

```
class User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

Main.ts:

```
/// <reference path="User.ts" />

// import { User } from "./user"; // not needed if referenced
console.log(new User());
```

all reference declarations have to be written at the beginning of the file

Comment: Wow, I've been searching on import vs reference for too many hours now, thank you so much! This was the root of my problem.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for me, I get this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963346/only-amd-and-system-modules-are-supported-alongside-out

Comment: @NickCoad looks like a problem with VisualStudio, i use Atom, PHPStorm and IntelliJ and all works fine.

Comment: @TypedSource I'm not doing this in Visual Studio, I'm doing it in the command line.

Comment: Struggled with this as well. Finally got it working with the module type set to "system". The commented out import line is required! I pushed a working example up to `github: https://github.com/medington/ts-reference`.

Comment: Also make sure your don't have "export" in front of the `User` class.

Comment: I get `error TS6082: Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --outFile`

Comment: I changed the tsconfig.json to use system instead of commonjs, included system.js in <head> and then added a <script> tag with System.defaultJSExtensions = true;
        System.import('main').then(function(namespace) { 
            new namespace.Main().start();
        });

Answer (score 9):

TypeScript by default uses node module resolution. Node.js / CommonJS uses **exports** keyword. However, CommonJS doesn't run in browser without a module loader or module bundler. Hence, you need browserify or webpack to get it running in browser.

Check out this link https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/gulp.html

You can also set *module* setting to none in *compiler options* section in *tsconfig.json*:

{
    "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "module": "none"
    }
}

Comment: this isn't correct. i run CommonJS in my browser without any problems. you can't use export and import in browser without an module loader, thats correct.

Comment: You are correct, I corrected my answer to be more explicit about it. You would need a module loader or module bundler to get CommonJS working in browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I now use [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/getting_started.html) to do the ugly stuff of transcoding etc.
My easiest config is the following:

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2015",
            "es5",
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "strict": false
    },
    "include": [ "lib/*", "./main.ts" ]
}
```

and in your HTML file, instead of importing the '.js', simply import the '.ts', like this:

```
<script src="main.ts"></script>
```

then, run Parcel with this command line:

```
parcel index.html
```

the Parcel bundler will create a **dist** directory containing all your needed files (html and transcoded JavaScript) and it will run a local webserver at:

> http://localhost:1234

with hot module reloading (in your browser window).

When you finish your work, you just have to deploy the **dist** directory ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Similar to TypedSource's answer, but if you can't or don't want to output into one js file you can do the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    <script src="~/scripts/user.js"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

User.ts :

```
class User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}
```

main.ts

```
/// <reference path="User.ts" />

// import { User } from "./user"; // not needed if referenced & User.js file is loaded
console.log(new User());
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my story:

I had the same problem because the browser uses modern `export/import` statement, while `Typescript` uses the default `commonJS`. So, in the `tsconfig.json` file, set the following changes:

```
target: "es2015",

module: "es2015",
```

I think if you use `BabolonJS`,it may be better to set `"moduleResolution`" to `"node"` explicitly, however it may make no difference.

Comment: Hi Mehdi.  Firstly, thank you for your contribution.  Perhaps you could improve it by framing the settings in a code block and making it clearer where in the essential code to apply those changes.  All contributions are valuable, so it's a worthwhile effort to present yours in the most helpful way possible.  In doing this you will increase the usability of your suggestions and improve the chances of receiving upvotes.  You might consider taking a look at the other answers to provide insight and inspiration in how to format your contribution.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

**my-enum.ts**

```
const MyEnum = {
'test': 456,
'Default': 123
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
import * as MyEnum from 'my-enum';
```