# TypeScript - exports is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have some files containing TypeScript classes, defined like this

textBox.ts

```
export class textBox {
//Variables here
//Constructor
constructor(idObj: number, textContent: string) {
    //More code
  }
}
```

I have another file, called userSlide.ts, which imports the class textBox like this

userSlide.ts

```
 import { textBox } from "./textBox";
```

When I run my code, I get this error

```
ReferenceError: exports is not defined
```

Edit: Here are the first few lines of the compiled file userSlide.js

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
var textBox_1 = require("./textBox");
var slide_1 = require("./slide");
```

I'm still new to TypeScript and have no idea how to fix this issue. I tried some other things, but to no effect

I'm using Visual Studio Code and have Node.js installed. I compiled them using the tsc command

Comment: Are you using any module loader?

Comment: I've tried with Webpack, but I cant seem to get it working

Comment: What are your filenames? Do they end with .ts? How do you build it? etc..

Comment: Edited to add the info.

Comment: did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43042889/typescript-referenceerror-exports-is-not-defined ?

Comment: @RezaRahmati - Yes, I tried commenting "module":"commnojs", and still no result. Also added the first line of code that tsc generates

Comment: Which version of node.js is that?

Comment: node -v returns v8.9.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472778/typescript-exports-is-not-defined)