# Undefine export after compile typescript to javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

I'm newbie use typescript. In my project have knockout ts, after compile (Intellij plugin auto compile ts -> js)

this is file sample.ts:

```
import * as ko from "knockout"; ko;

class HelloViewModel {
    language: KnockoutObservable<string>
    framework: KnockoutObservable<string>

    constructor(language: string, framework: string) {
        this.language = ko.observable(language);
        this.framework = ko.observable(framework);
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new HelloViewModel("TypeScript", "Knockout"));
```

sample.js:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var ko = require("knockout");
ko;
var HelloViewModel = /** @class */ (function () {
    function HelloViewModel(language, framework) {
        this.language = ko.observable(language);
        this.framework = ko.observable(framework);
    }
    return HelloViewModel;
}());
ko.applyBindings(new HelloViewModel("TypeScript", "Knockout"));
```

when run on browser it notice error: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined at sample.js:2

I try to search but still not find solution.
Please show me if you have a way to solve it.

This my project:  https://github.com/hoangdangduy/StreamingVideoWeb

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `define` statement in your JS file.  It should look more like:

```
define(["require", "exports", "knockout"], function (require, exports, ko) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    ko;
    var HelloViewModel = /** @class */ (function () {
        function HelloViewModel(language, framework) {
            this.language = ko.observable(language);
            this.framework = ko.observable(framework);
        }
        return HelloViewModel;
    }());
    ko.applyBindings(new HelloViewModel("TypeScript", "Knockout"));
});
```

This is from copy-pasting your code into the [TypeScript REPL](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Also, you can change

```
import * as ko from "knockout"; ko;
```

to

```
import ko from "knockout";
```

Comment: file js was automatic compile by plugin so I don't want add define manually.
And I also try to add 'define' as you say but still notice error 'define is not defined'

Comment: Ah, I see. Then see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472778/typescript-exports-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

`require`/`exports` do not exist in the browser.

You will need to use a bundler in addition to TypeScript, such as webpack.

Alternatively, you can try using the `"module": "umd"` in your `tsconfig.json`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I solved it, I use add requirejs to load module after my file ts and knokout ts was compiled.