# Classes and Interfaces with or without export keyword in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning angular, picked a video course and a pdf book and now i am confused with respect to "export" keyword use...

Course one (pdf) is using Angular 5 and visual studio 2017.

Course two (video) is using Angular 6 and visual studio Code.

Following thread talks about export and why we need it so kind of good with the definition:

[Why does Typescript use the keyword "export" to make classes and interfaces public?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15760462/why-does-typescript-use-the-keyword-export-to-make-classes-and-interfaces-publ)

An example from both the courses to show my confusion... I just need a quick kick in the right direction to overcome this small hurdle.

**Visual Studio 2017**

Example project made me create an interface folder inside ClientApp/App folder and inside it placed one interface "answer.ts". This is without the keyword "export".

```
interface IAnswer {
    Id: number;
    QuestionId: number;
    Text: string;
    Value: number;
}
```

Then in the component,  used it without importing it. Take a look at the loadData function, `this.http.get<IAnswer[]>(url).subscribe`. IAnswer is being used, it is without the export keyword and no import in the component.

```
import { Component, Inject, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
    selector: "answer-list",
    templateUrl: "./answer-list.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./answer-list.component.css"]
})

export class AnswerListComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() question: IQuestion;
    answers: IAnswer[];
    title: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        @Inject("BASE_URL") private baseUrl: string,
        private router: Router) {

        this.answers = [];
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (typeof changes['question'] !== "undefined") {
            //alert(1);
            // retrieve the question variable change info
            var change = changes['question'];

            // only perform the task if the value has been changed
            if (!change.isFirstChange()) {
                // execute the Http request and retrieve the result
                this.loadData();
            }
        }
    }

    loadData() {
        var url = this.baseUrl + "api/answer/All/" + this.question.Id;
        this.http.get<IAnswer[]>(url).subscribe(res => {
            this.answers = res;
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}
```

**Visual Studio Code**

Here if i don't create a class with export keyword then i can't use it in any component or a service, import is needed as well. Placed a recipe.model.ts in src/app/recipes folder.

```
export class Recipe {
    constructor(public name: string, public description: string, public imagePath: string){
    }
}
```

Then i have a service which gets/post/push data from/to Firebase in this example, so omitting un-related code to this question.

```
import { Recipe } from "../../recipes/recipe.model";

@Injectable()
export class DataStorageService {
    getRecipes(){
        //get a authentication token
        const token = this.authService.getToken();
        const tokenQuery = '?auth=' + token

        this.http.get(this.recipesNode + tokenQuery)
        .pipe(
            map(
                (response: Response) => {
                    //we saved array of recipes 
                    const recipes: Recipe[] = response.json();
                    return recipes;
                }
            )
        )
        .subscribe(
            (recipes: Recipe[]) => {
                this.recipeService.setRecipes(recipes);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the set `compilerOptions` in your project. You can force the system to expect or not expect `export`. Usually this decision is made according to the question whether you use WebPack, Browserify or other modular loaders or you just want to transpile the given *.ts-files into *.js-files. Please, have a look at this post:

[TypeScript exports is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43472778/typescript-exports-is-not-defined)

Comment: I should have mentioned this before. VS 2017 used the SPA template which uses `WebPack` and then the course is building on top of it. And vs code started the project with `> ng new somthing`. tsconfig entries are default in both cases. Thanks for clarifying!