# Error - Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --outFile

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code

Trying to compile an Angular project in Visual Studio Code with `ng build` and serve it with `ng serve`

In both cases got the following error:

> Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --outFile

[image: Error]

[Didn't use --outFile option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963346/only-amd-and-system-modules-are-supported-alongside-out) for compiling and serving so don't really know where the error is.

Also tried to remove `"module": "commonjs"` from tsconfig.spec.json as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963346/only-amd-and-system-modules-are-supported-alongside-out) but still not working.

- **tsConfig.spec.json**

[image: tsConfig.json]

Any idea on how to solve this error? Thanks!

Comment: Please paste text instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration includes `"outFile": "./dist/out-tsc/app/build.js"` which is equivalent to the `--outFile` flag. Remove this line from the configuration and rely on the `outDir` only.